# Datastax Java Cassandra Driver: Multiple AND statements using WHERE?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to run the following CQL statement using the latest Datastax Cassandra driver for Java:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column_one=1 AND column_2=9 AND column_3=50;
```

Here's what I have so far (only 2 ANDs), but I can't find a way to chain more than 2 where Clauses using and():

```
Statement select = QueryBuilder.select().all().from( "tablename").where(QueryBuilder.eq("column_one", 1)).and(QueryBuilder.eq("column_two", 9));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should work:

```java
    Statement s = QueryBuilder.select().all()
        .from("tableName")
        .where(eq("column_1", 1))
        .and(eq("column_2", 9))
        .and(eq("column_3", 50));
```

It produces the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE column_1=1 AND column_2=9 AND column_3=50;
```

Comment: In spark_cassandra_connector 1.6.1 .where(Querybuilder.eq("column",val))

Comment: Can you share updated query for new version of driver? After version 4.x, QueryBuilder api is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Statement select = QueryBuilder.select().from("tableName").
where(QueryBuilder.eq("field","value"));
```

This is another example, the eq method is contained in the CQL QueryBuilder.